# Programatically identifing feature for activation

Tags: feature, feature-activation, feature-receiver

I have a requirement where a custom action is only added to the root site of the site collection. So planning to add two features one `Site` scoped and the other `Web` scoped.
In the event receiver of a `Site` scoped feature, I'm activating the `Web` scope feature.

For this i can use

```
web.Features.Add(webFeatureId);
```

How can I find the web level features feature id programmatically ?

Comment: I have edited the question to be more clear. If anything else come to mind, feel free to improve it and add more info as required. For example, do you have any restriction about the feature you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well. It really depends on which feature you have to activate.

The id of a feature does not change during its life. This means that if you can find out the id you will be sure it stays the same, regardless of the specific SharePoint farm instance. That said, you can "hardcode" your ID in a support class, much like SharePoint does with fields id in the SPBuiltInFields class.

If for any reason you can't know the feature ID beforehand you will need some other way to identify the feature - for example the display name. With that info you can use the [FeatureDefinitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.featuredefinitions.aspx) property of the SPWeb object to browse the installed 'Web' level features, search the one you need and add it to the [Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.features.aspx) collection to activate it as required.

Comment: I used the featureID from feature Properties in Visual Studio and activated the feature in the code. Many Thanks !